# Add new button to Tinymce toolbar c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, tinymce

I have used Tinymce textedior/textarea on my page. How can I add a new button on the toolbar? for example. When i click the button on the toolbar it should open a new dialog with 3 textfields. like
title
age
gender

When you fill out the textfields and press ok, I want this to be the result depend on your answer
[title = "" age="" gender=""]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably make a click function that opens a dialog.

Put details in the textfields and voilà.